# Figma Emailify Plugin, How to Add a Hyperlink to an Image? Can't add 0% Opacity text layer for some reason

Tags: html, figma, e-mail

I am using the Emailify Plugin for Figma and noticed that I cannot add a Link to images/ icons. I want to add a clickable URL to each of the social media icons. There is another question from a year ago describing a work-around where you place an equal-sized text box at 0% opacity that people click to Link to the social media or other hyperlinks.

Please help! What is the workaround? I am not strong in HTML but I could figure out how to edit the code to add the hyperlink once I export it... I think.

Comment: According to their documentation it looks like you do it just like you'd make a text link: [Select image > add link URL](https://docs.figmatic.com/emailify/usage.html#adding-links-and-alt-text). If that doesn't work, you should probably contact them directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert links on Figma by selecting the text, pressing *Command + K* then adding the URL. When you hover you can edit the link as well.

For your reference see this [video](https://youtu.be/OS50jRYp9gg).

Hope this will help you, thank you :)

Comment: Hi Sumit, strangely it is not this simple with *images,* I am still trying to figure this one out for the Emailify Plugin, not just for Figma

Answer (score 0):

The one workaround I found was to upload it to the email service I use and open it with the rich text editor. I don't know anything about coding, but then it just allows me to double click on the button and add a url to the image. Hope that helps!